# MiKTeX exception caught: Unknown MiKTeX exception with asymptote

Tags: latex, asymptote

Since updating packages from Miktek I have an error :

2020-12-27 17:05:41,781+0100 ERROR asy - MiKTeX exception caught: Unknown MiKTeX exception.

The files .pre and .tex aren't created. I don't understand why?

thanks for help et sorry for my english

Comment: I also noticed that Pdfadd has a problem for the preview. It doesn't work. There is a problem but where?

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: When i do that it woks :

Comment: size(6cm,0);

path segm1=(-1,-1)--(5,2),
    segm2=(0,3)--(2,-3);
draw(segm1^^segm2,blue);

dot(intersectionpoint(segm1,segm2),4bp+red);

shipout(bbox(3mm,white));

Comment: But not whith : size(6cm,0);
import math;

// Placement de 4 points
pair A=(0,0),B=(2,2),C=(0,5),D=(5,1);
dot("$A$",A,SE);
dot("$B$",B,SE);
dot("$C$",C,N);
dot("$D$",D,N);

// Tracé de [AB] et [CD]
draw(A--B,blue);
draw(C--D,red);

// Construction du point
// d'intersection de (AB) et (CD)
pair pI=extension(A,B,C,D);
dot("$I$",pI,N,red);
draw(B--pI,1pt+dotted);

Comment: My file filename-1.pdf is not found when i use a certain type of content inside \begin{asy} ... \end{asy}

Comment: I noticed a problem with label with dot() and draw(). If i do : dot((0,0),SE) ;
draw((0,0)--dir(45),Arrow); there isn't problem but if i do : dot("$A$",(0,0));
draw(Label("r"),(0,0)--dir(45),Arrow); there is a problem!!!